# Doctrine wants to "ALTER TABLE coo_users CHANGE id id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;" but wants to do this each time I update the schema

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

If I do `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` the result is:

> Updating database schema...
>   Database schema updated successfully! "1" query was executed

And this is done each time I run the `update` command.

So, with `bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` I see that:

> [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
>   [Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.

The query Doctrine wants to execute is ever the same (`bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`):

```
ALTER TABLE coo_users CHANGE id id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
```

**What's happening? It seems Doctrine wants to do any modification as it wants to change the field `id` again to field `id`, each time, in an infinite modification.**

THE MAPPING

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error found!

The problem is that the column type is set to `string` while it has to be `integer`.

It was set to `string` as I used a custom generator that required a `string` field. When I removed the custom generator, I didn't change the field type back to `integer` and so Doctrine wanted to edit the field each time.